# Why does Mercurial sometimes allow merging with an ancestor?

Tags: mercurial, merge, branch, dvcs

I'm puzzled by [this repo history](https://bitbucket.org/lorien/grab/changesets/a57326ec3e4a). On that page, you'll see a small branch `file-content` which is merged back to the branch `default` even though one head was an ancestor of the other.

<strike>When I try doing something similar I get an abort message unless</strike>

1. the side branch is closed and
2. I merge from the ancestor to the closed branch head (but not the other way around). (In this grab repo, the `file-content` branch is marked inactive, not closed.)

Edit: the real conditions under which you can merge with an ancestor are described in my answer.

So what's going on here?

Answer (score 5):

This is strangely poorly documented, but if you follow the link at the bottom of https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Merge, you'll see there's an exception to the rule against merging with an ancestor. It doesn't require the descendant to be a closed branch as I originally surmised. Instead:

1. You must merge from the ancestor (i.e. the working directory must be updated to the ancestor, not the other changeset)
2. The branch names of the working directory's parent and of the changeset with which you're merging must differ. E.g. one has branch name default, the other has branch name feature-X

What this allows us, then, is the ability to start a new branch and merge it back even if we do no work on the original branch in the interim.

Answer (score 3):

There's no technical reason why you cannot merge with an ancestor: as you've found out, Mercurial does support it in some circumstances. So it's purely a GUI restriction. The reasoning behind this is that when `hg update` would give you the same result as `hg merge`, then you should use that instead for simplicity.

A *merge* is just a mix of three repository states: the common ancestor and the two changesets you're merging. Three-way merging is done on a hunk by hunk basis. The table for merging local with remote looks like this:

```
ancestor  local  remote -> merge
old       old    old       old (nobody changed the hunk)
old       new    old       new (I changed the hunk)
old       old    new       new (you changed the hunk)
old       new    new       new (hunk was cherry picked onto both branches)
old       foo    bar       <!> (conflict, both changed hunk but differently)
```

If `local` is an ancestor of `remote`, then `ancestor == local`. So the table becomes:

```
ancestor  local  remote -> merge
old       old    old       old (nobody changed the hunk)
old       old    new       new (you changed the hunk)
```

In both cases, the `merge` column contain what was in the `remote` column. In your example, `local` is `default` and `remote` is `file-content`:

```
$ hg update default
$ hg merge file-content
```

The result is a merge changeset that looks just like `file-content`.

Comment: Request for publish this topic also

Comment: So what commands were used in this example to get this changeset history? I can't recreate it at the command line.